# FD_CLOSE event in winsock

Tags: windows, sockets, events, winsock

I am developing an http client using event-driven winsock sockets. But I'm confused about how to handle FD_CLOSE messages. At certain situtations, I receive FD_CLOSE even tough there is still data to be read in the socket. So my current code goes like this:

```
WSAEventSelect(s,hevent,FD_READ | FD_WRITE | FD_CLOSE);
while (1)
{
    WaitForSingleEvent(hevent,TIMEOUT);
    WSAEnumNetworkEvents(s,hevent,&netevent);
    if ((netevent.lNetworkEvents & FD_READ) || (netevent.lNetworkEvents & FD_CLOSE))
    {
        do
        {
            resrecv=recv(s,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
            if (resrecv<0)
                throw "recv failed";
            if (resrecv==0)                 
                break;
           /*
           Handle the message here.
           */

        } while (netevents.lNetworkEvents & FD_CLOSE);
    }
    /*
    Write response to the socket. (If we received all of the request)
    */
    if (netevent.lNetworkEvents & FD_CLOSE)
    {
        closesocket(s);
        break;
    }
}
```

It basically reads as much data as it can once an FD_CLOSE is received. But when it receives an FD_READ, it issues only one recv. This approach seems to work so far but it looks weird to me, especially the do-while part. And I'm afraid this will turn out to be buggy at some point in the future. What is the correct way of handling FD_CLOSE? I couldn't find any example in msdn or Windows SDK.

(I ommitted some obvious error checks in the snippet above.)

Edit : Here are two demo programs that can be used to observe this behaviour :

[Download Code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xgu7ph4qipfqev1/AACCv42dL3VYeoGqsxCxv2jpa?dl=0)

Comment: It looks good to me, but I'm surprised you get them both at once. Otherwise everybody would have this problem. Are you sure about that?

Comment: This seems to happen when one end sends a long message and gracefully closes the socket before the other end receives it completely. At least, this is what two demo programs running on the same system says.

Comment: You might be better off ignoring FD_CLOSE altogether and just reacting to getting zero from `recv()` on FD_READ.

Comment: That would work, I guess. But then, why does FD_CLOSE even exist?

Comment: I guess to catch the corner case you found.